# Is it possible to dynamically add views in cloudant (couchdb) through node.js using nano

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

I am using `cloudant-couchdb` for the first time and I just got stuck with this problem. 
I am trying to insert a view into my database dynamically through my node.js server.

Here is my code.

```
app.post("/listSections", function(req, res) {      
  var moduleID = req.body.name;                             
  console.log(moduleID);        
  db.insert(
        { "views":
            { moduleID:     //create view with name = moduleID
                { 
                    "map": function (doc) {
                       //some function
                }
            }
        }, 
        '_design/section', function (error, response) {
                console.log("Success!");        
   });          
});
```

I want to create a view dynamically with the view name being the value of the variable moduleID. How can I pass that variable in the insert function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names cannot be interpolated in object literal definitions.  Create the object beforehand.

```
var obj = {};
obj[moduleID] = {map: function () {}};

db.insert({views: obj},
```

If you are using ES6 and computed property names are available, you can do this instead:

```
db.insert({views: {[moduleID]: {
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you so much.

However, I am only able to add a single view with it. It won't add new views (with different moduleID's) on multiple post requests.

Comment: This code works, but only for the first view. It wont add views after the first name - "Error: Document update conflict".

Comment: @KashifKai views must have unique names.  If you want to create another view, it needs a different name (or you must delete the original view)